# Typescrit interface for an object of arrow functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, arrow-functions

I'v faced a problem trying to define an interface for the following structure:

```js
interface JSONRecord {
  [propName: string]: any;
}
type ReturnType = (id: string|number, field: string, record: JSONRecord) => string

export const formatDictionary = ({
  mode = "render", key = "originalValue",
  defaultKey = "originalValue"
}):ReturnType => (id, field, record) => {
  ...
}

interface Lookup {
  Dictionary: ({mode, key, defaultKey}:{mode: string, key: string, defaultKey: string}) => ReturnType,
  ...
}
export const functionLookup:Lookup = {
  Dictionary: formatDictionary,
  ...
}
export const formatField = (params:JSONRecord):string|ReturnType => {
  const type:string = params.type
  if (type === undefined) { return identity }
  const fn = functionLookup[type]
  if (fn === undefined) { return identity }
  return fn({ ...params })
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

1. In line `const fn = functionLookup[type]` : Element implicitly has an 'any' type becasue expression of type string can't be used to index type 'Lookup'. No index signature with parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Lookup'.

- I'm not really sure why is this happening, i thought that the Dictionary i defined in Lookup is supposed to be interpreted as a string. When i change Dictionary to `[x: string]:  ({mode, key, defaultKey}:{mode: string, key: string, defaultKey: string}) => ReturnType` the error disappears, but i want to be specific with the arguments that can be passed.

2. In line `return fn({ ...params })` : Expected 3 arguments, but got 1

- I can't really wrap my head around this, the function is clearly expecting only 1 object as an argument `{mode, key, defaultKey}` or is it expecting the ReturnType function there?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: please share reproducable example. `identity` is not defined variable

Comment: Hi @captain-yossarian Thanks for your answer. I'v created a codesandbox with a much simpler example that results in the same error. https://codesandbox.io/s/0p1od?file=/index.ts i still can't understand what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case (from sandbox):

```js
const anExampleVariable = "Hello World"
console.log(anExampleVariable)

// To learn more about the language, click above in "Examples" or "What's New".
// Otherwise, get started by removing these comments and the world is your playground.

interface Lookup {
    test: number
}
const functionLookup:Lookup = {
    test: 5
}

const params = {
    type: 'test'
};
const type = params.type
const a = functionLookup[type]
```

`params` variable is infered as `{type: string}`.

Here `functionLookup[type]` you want use `type` as index for `functionLookup`, but TS does not work that way. Because you can't just use general type `string` as index for `Lookup` type.

`Lookup` allows you to use only literal `test` as index.

So you can add `as const` prefix to your `params` vvariable.

```js
const params = {
    type: 'test'
} as const;
```

You can make Lookup indexed:

```js
interface Lookup {
    test: number,
    [prop:string]:number
}
```

Or, you can explicitly define a Record type for `params`:

```js
const params:Record<string, keyof Lookup> = {
    type: 'test'
}
```

Comment: I understand now where i got lost there, but isn't it just saying now that every string is now acceptable and will be looked for in the functionLookup? so i should expect undefined value if the wrong string is passed?

Comment: It depends on your logic. If you will stick with `[prop:string]:number`, then - yes.  Value can be undefined. If U dont want undefined value, then U probable should use `Record<string, keyof Lookup>`